# Two sliders with one navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, synchronization, slider

In my new project I need two sliders (or one slider conected with tabs).

Here is example
http://oi39.tinypic.com/2yyxxlx.jpg

When I click on the NEXT or PREV (of the top slider) content ( in red box under the slider) must change to another content.

I need connection between two red boxes with one navigation. It must be synch.

Can you help me with it?

I use `BXSLIDER`

Here is the code

```
<div class="slider1">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slider/1.jpg" />
        <div class="over-text">
            <h2>ZAŽI RAKETOVÝ ŠTART</h2>
            <a href="">link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slider/2.jpg" />
        <div class="over-text">
            <h2>ZAŽI RAKETOVÝ ŠTART</h2>
            <a href="">link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.slider1').bxSlider({
         slideWidth: 1200,
         minSlides: 1,
         maxSlides: 1,
         slideMargin: 0,
         pause: 8000,
         speed: 500,
         controls: true,
         auto: true,
         autoStart: false
     });
 });   
</script>
```

(sorry, my english is very bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly then you could use the [plugin's methods](http://bxslider.com/options).
Define some operations with `onSlideNext` or `onSlidAfter` that operate on your other div.
I don't know how you might get your content, AJAX `load()`?
Or straight from code? Anyway that's the best method in my opinion.
So my idea is something like this, but I let you fine tune it.
First of all define your sliders so that they belong to a variable and you can easily call methods on them:

```
mySlide1 = $('.slider1').bxSlider({ 
    //code code code
}
mySlide2 = $('.slider2').bxSlider({
    //code code code
}
```

Then add this line to your options in slider1:

```
onSlideAfter: function() { mySlide2.goToNexSlide()};
```

This way the second slider will change slide when you click on the first one.
Alternatively you can set up any code in the callback to obtain the result you need.

Comment: Hi Alan, 
content will by load from the (static) code. (If it possible)
If I have fe. four sliders of BXSLIDER I have the same number of DIV under the slider. It must be synch.

basically I need two sliders that I will be operated with one navigation. When I Clicked to NEXT/PREV both sliders are switch at the same time.

Can you show me some example code of your idea please? I think that you understood me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different plugin but I really think it is the best and most flexible out there, it's Cycle 2, here is a link to a jsfiddle I just made: http://jsfiddle.net/cp6mN/, the important part is the `data-cycle-next` and `data-cycle-prev` attributes of the slider div and creating the buttons with the elements yo declare there.

Comment: That is what I need, but it only works with IMG? cause in the second slideshow I need DIV with  content, not IMG. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It works with anything you tell to work with, you need to add `data-cycle-slides` attribute and fill it with something like `> div` or maybe just `div`, you can see all API options here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: @Matrinkoo did it work? if it did, please mark my answer as correct.